# Downloading code is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download

When I am downloading an image it's displaying these characters on screen.

```
�M\cIDATx��\i��v�U�ݳ��x���6`8�Y�&@��#D �����HDʟ'�~�z;a���D,�c������ƌ���ٺ�*�w�=շjz^z�ـ���UwWWݺ�;�|g��&H���o�Gy���~s��K۲e�y�7�ѣG�̙3ͤI������3�O=�T���n�z�)�k�.�p�B��NJ��6m���؄a(�ٳgOt��i���|����hhh((�˦����{����3��sO�C�:�_�k�������s�)�|X�V��_C�6���2o~G���3����y۶m��o4�\s�) r�ܹse.|-[�,�`~/N� GQdU(h!Z� |E���J��h�&�u�sާ�ES�T���æ��ׯh�o�>���ˡ�ˠ�-��-m�{ �\p�@Mo؅u�֙���{�qN;,�ŋ�cߏ䦦&3u�T���)��MS�yrP���B|o���Ԏ�l1�C&L8�����j�j/_4ϯ���4��o�o��w�>|8�5���M�P�;f���͆ Ҿ&N�hJM%C�,Z�� Z=�9螞�=~��4�7H�������@���-"0�jWW�1���{[[[�:;'�Θ1�0�+�^h�h�>��#�Aw�;�� ��Ba�J%�ޓ���;�����с� ���4�2�<xͩt�8��="" p�ٴi�����="" 4g�q8��:��u�9q:v�i��x(���r�b��m��n��f�ml���="" ���)��n�="" ="" -��="" ���o����+�itj�_⧟~"Ȣ="" Ԯj��`�!�x��sn��n�g��'�j��cmv��o="" !�����?������޷r���p��(��)�,Ԭ^�z�0k֬���ŀh�`�5�'��1�����&\��+�2�o="" �v��4�="" �ac="" ��="" 4�f+�e�="" �ӭ�w����j���q�#�)��t̟??��x4�7e���oh�6o޼���r&�lh�z�n��l�8��pn���kἎbhj�e�-�|!�*���ɪ��z="">�E��Ŵ��;���Ʃ�0����j\�]o^�X�A�qο�8cVh�Q�M�x��F](L3�@'f�T�*4�IxZ,K8��͜ ! ���S��MJ�h� 5��2��p�!��wۇ�n� �M�/Z�c�=&Q��_h&�8� �X8��.��鑪&uRL���b�j�~Wg���A �d@MUG(�+�B_r�$�h�w ���i 2���ʠ>�QƸ�v�e�n�~|�fm�1� D��6K�w{����z��7T0�����}���ĩ@��Q�8K�Q�"�8�^2��d�N�+l�$j3�j����h'�x�V.��qmA�����P�?[� ^bIFE�Q����#�{i���o��� �:�<&��Y���Ѳ%�L�U��܍�����ź�ZB�\���*N��X� G!*=w�J@-���k5� m��\ 7�8O~��,��=�݄}Jp�?�P�L)�P��j4F�����"Ds:��I�o���^{M����*4H#�
```

And I used this code for downloading

```
$fn = $path.'/'.$file_name;

$mm_type="application/octet-stream";
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fn)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($fn);
```

Comment: can I know what is the value of the `$file_name` variable when you meet the problem? I have tried with your code and found no error. You can add `var_dump($fn); die()` before `$mm_type=....` and give me the output.

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe $fn=http://thetexturemill.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dell.png and $file_name=dell.png

Comment: My code work with your file. You can take a look at my answer and tell me the result.

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe give me your answer which work proper

Comment: @Hamender it is at bellow http://stackoverflow.com/a/17721224/1399505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with your code and found no problem. After read your comment and try with your file `thetexturemill.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dell.png` I have this code working:

```
# my demo value in my local machine
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/demo";
$file_name = "Capture.PNG";    
#$fn = realpath($path.'/'.$file_name);
$fn = "http://thetexturemill.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dell.png";
//var_dump(readfile($fn));

$mm_type="application/octet-stream";
#$mm_type=mime_content_type($fn);
#echo $mm_type; die();
ob_get_flush();
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
#header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fn)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($fn);
flush();
die();
```

What problems I found are:

- If you use an image from remote host, make sure you can get it (the `allow_url_fopen` INI option is `ON` and the returned value from `readfile` is greater than zero) and do not use `filesize` as well as `mime_content_type` functions.
- I don't know whether `thetexturemill.com` is your domain name or folder name. Supposed that it is a domain name, remember to add the protocal prefix (`http://` as in example)
- Do not output anything before the `header` function calls or your downloaded file will not be open properly.

Ah, for local file, your original code work without errors on my machine.

Comment: @Trun-HieuLe when i execute on localhost this warning with same charactor Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/download/downloading.php:12) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/download/downloading.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/download/downloading.php:12) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/download/downloading.php on line 14

Comment: Can you tell me exactly the location of the PHP download file and how you use it in wordpress. Do you use it in a plugin or a theme? This could help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The content type is wrong

```
application/octet-stream
```

Ocet-stream is used for executable files which images are not for sure.

A proper type for a image for jpg image is for example:

```
image/jpeg
```

You can use [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to get proper content type of file

> Returns the MIME content type for a file as determined by using information from the magic.mime file.

Try this code

```
$fn = $path.'/'.$file_name;
$mime = mime_content_type($fn);
header('Content-Type:'.$mime);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fn));
readfile($fn);
```

Comment: i also tried this but it's not working

Comment: header ('Content-type: image/png');
  header ('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.'dell.png'. ';');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fn1));
  readfile($fn1);

Comment: are you sure that it is proper image file?

Comment: @Hamender check my code in edited version.

Comment: yes @Robert,it's png image

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $fn = $path.'/'.$file_name;
    $mm_type="application/octet-stream";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fn)) );
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fn.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fn);
    exit;
?>
```

Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: yes @Rohan i try, now it's show the login window

Comment: @Hamender test the above again.

Comment: again login window open with these special characters

Comment: Remove the `ob_clean();` line and then test it.

Comment: i remove it but not any effect, same result login page with these characters

Comment: Show your full code, what you have tried?

Comment: Read this also http://wordpress.org/plugins/filedownload/